# Can a tablet device be used as a console to monitor the boot process of a CentOS/RedHat server?

Tags: centos, boot, startup, serial, bluetooth

Can a `tablet` device (e.g., Fire HD 8 tablet) be used as a `console`, to monitor the `boot process` of a `CentOS/RedHat server`?

For instance, is it possible to connect a BlueTooth adapter to the tablet's micro-B connector,
and another Bluetooth Serial adapter to the Linux server's RS232 port,
and then set the boot process such that its output will go to BlueTooth via the serial port,
and thus - show on the tablet?

Will such a configuration allow the tablet to control the boot process? E.g., stop it and go into the BIOS to change the boot device?

If I build a CentOS kernel where serial support is compiled into the kernel (i.e., is not a module), with that help?

Comment: You still have rs232 ports on your servers????

Comment: In theory you could do that, but whether you could get the BIOS on the serial port is ... unlikely. You should be using remote management anyway (IPMI, iDRAC, ILO, etc).

Comment: On some of them, yes, @symcbean.

Comment: Ah, @Michael, if only it were you who's in charge of authorising expenses at my startup...

Comment: Given how much time you're likely to spend on ideas like this one before coming to the conclusion they won't work, the time it will cost to go in to manage the servers when it could be done remotely, and Covid-19 on top, it's an easy purchase decision.